# How to use anchor in Wordpress permalinks

Tags: wordpress, anchor, permalinks

I'll try to explain my need as best I can. When I create a new post in WordPress, the permalink is automatically generated. The permalink is also present within the post and can be modified manually later. If I wanted to add an anchor the `#` symbol is replaced by `-`. Same thing for `myUrl/#my-anchor` becomes `myUrl-my-anchor` and this of course doesn't work.

I would like the ability to provide a link to a post that, when clicked, allows the post to be viewed, or scrolled, at a specific position. Even a function that calls a specific `#layout` ID that I have in every single post would be perfect.

Searching the web I found different topics but they all talk about how to create anchors using the text editor but that's not what I'm looking for.

I use a child theme so I could also work on the `functions.php`.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has special filters, such as `post_link`, `page_link`, `post_type_link`, `category_link`, and so on.
For example, if you want to add a link hash to a `post` with `id === 123`, do something like this:

```php
add_filter( 'post_link', 'my_post_link', 10, 3 );

function my_post_link( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    if ( $post->ID === 123 ) {
        $permalink = $permalink . '#hash';
    }
    return $permalink;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @imhvost, this is a good solution, but I would have to add a new post ID every time. It would be decisive to be able to have a function that is not limited to a post ID but which, for example, can consider all the posts that will have `#readmore`.

Can this be done?

Comment: `if ( $post->ID === 121 )` is just an example. You can take `$post->post_content` and search a block with `id="readmore"`. Or create a meta field for the posts (for example the `is_has_readmore` `checkbox`), and apply the `'post_link'` filter to those posts that have `is_has_readmore`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much @imhvost,

I solved it this way. At the beginning of each post the WordPress theme inserts the "layout" ID which represents the exact beginning of the content. With this function, where I hope I haven't made any mistakes, each post is loaded exactly at that point.

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'my_post_link', 10, 3 );

function my_post_link( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    if ( $post->post_content ) {
        $permalink = $permalink . '#layout';
    }
    return $permalink;
}
```